# `top` not refreshing screen on exit

Tags: shell, top, xterm

When I exit `top`, the prompt reappears at the bottom and I can see the bottom of the last thing it was showing. How can I get `top` to behave like `less` i.e. refresh the screen back to when I launched `top`?

`htop` seems to do this, but it is not available on the machine I am ssh-ing into. My terminal is `xterm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `tput` on that system, you can use:

```
tput smcup ; top ; tput rmcup
```

You can put that in an alias, if you prefer to always use that when you invoce `top`:

```
alias top='tput smcup ; top ; tput rmcup'
```